# PROFINET gsdml to gsd file conversion

Tags: wireshark

Is there a way of conversion from GSDML (GSD*.xml) file to a plain GSD file?
I have an GSDML file and the Wireshark that I use to decode messages is only accepting GSD files.

Or maybe without conversion: is there a way to convince Wireshark to use GSDML file?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark can use GSDML files out of the box as mentioned by Filip. You select your GSDML file in Wireshark through **Edit > Preferences > Protocols > PNIO**. Then select the *folder* where a single GSDML file is stored which you want to use.

The conversion of a .GSD to a .GSDML file is not possible. They are used for [different formats](https://www.profibus.com/download/gsdml-gsdx-specification-for-profinet):

> The GSD (General Station Description) is the device description
> technology for PROFIBUS and PROFINET. It comes in two flavors:
>
> - The PB-GSD for **PROFIBUS** Masters and Slaves using **GSDL** (GSD Language, keyword based), and
> - The PN-GSD for **PROFINET** Devices using **GSDML** (GSD Markup Language, XML based)

Comment: Looks like it is possible to use GSDML now:
https://rt-labs.com/docs/p-net/capturing_packets.html
But honestly I have not tried it yet.

Comment: @Filip you are right, Wireshark can use GSDML files.